# Nodejs Series Async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
var identifiers = getIdentifiers();
for(var i = 0; i < identifiers.length; i++){
  async.series({
    country:   function(){return getCountry(identifiers[i])},
    price:  function(){return getPrice(identifiers[i])}
    }, function(err, result) {
    console.log("Country: " + result.country + ", Price: " + result.price);
    });
}
```

Thanks for the feedback. What I am trying to achieve is to get a string composed of "Country: " + result[0] + ", Price: " + result[1]. Currently I have "Country: undefied, Price: undefined".

```
var identifiers = getIdentifiers();
for(var i = 0; i < identifiers.length; i++){
  async.series([
    function(callback){
      getCountry(identifiers[i], function(result) {
        callback(result);
    })},
    function(callback){
      getPrice(identifiers[i], function(result) {
        callback(result);
    })}
    ], function(err, result) {
      console.log("Country: " + result[0] + ", Price: " + result[1]);
    });
}
```

Comment: You only used 2 spaces for indenting.

Comment: Before someone tells you what is wrong with this code you should explain the problem you are trying to solve, what is the expected and the actual output from it and how does the actual output differs from the expected: basically ask a proper question on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're using async.series but none of your functions take callbacks. Async takes an array of functions, but you passed it an object with functions in it. Lastly, none of your functions look asynchronous, so I don't know what you're trying to achieve with async.

Comment: Your series functions (can be object) has no callbacks.  this part: country:   function().. you need the get & run the callback when its finished. otherwise async will not able to execute the second function and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see the edits above.

Comment: your callbacks are wrong. async expects 2 parameters. first is for error. second is for result.. i will post an answer for correct usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async series callbacks work with 2 parameters. first for errors & second for result.

```
var identifiers = getIdentifiers();
for(var i = 0; i < identifiers.length; i++){
  async.series([
    function(callback){
      getCountry(identifiers[i], function(result) {
        callback(null, result);
    })},
    function(callback){
      getPrice(identifiers[i], function(result) {
        callback(null, result);
    })}
    ], function(err, result) {
      console.log("Country: " + result[0] + ", Price: " + result[1]);
    });
}
```

sending "null" for error. but of course you can actually get an error from `getPrice` and `getCountry` then pass it to async.